# Could not find the error in App Script code for creating rows in Google Sheets and filling-up data based on user inputs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a number of rows in a Sheet after the last row having the specified date (F5 cell value) and based on user inputs in H5, I5, J5, K5 cells (some of them may be blank). User inputs are taken in the Dashboard Sheet, which is attached herewith this post. And the sheet where the data will be stored is specified in F5 having following format:

```
Date              Student ID      Umail                             Latitude  Longitude Subject
2020-08-20 (G5)   1902011 (H5)    1902011@icte.bdu.ac.bd (H5 + K3)    -         -       ICTE4115 (F5)
2020-08-20 (G5)   1902015 (I5)    1902015@icte.bdu.ac.bd (I5 + K3)    -         -       ICTE4115 (F5)
2020-08-20 (G5)   1902024 (J5)    1902024@icte.bdu.ac.bd (J5 + K3)    -         -       ICTE4115 (F5)
2020-08-20 (G5)   1902036 (K5)    1902036@icte.bdu.ac.bd (K5 + K3)    -         -       ICTE4115 (F5)
```

My codes are: When values in K6 cell selected, the function onePeriod() will be called.

```
function onePeriod(){
  // For a single Period Class
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dashboard = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Dashboard");
  var sheetName = dashboard.getRange("F5").getValue();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  
  var umailPattern = dashboard.getRange("K3").getValue();
  
  //Locate the lastrow of the specified date  
  var mDate = dashboard.getRange("G5").getDisplayValue();  
  var startRow = 2;
  var dateColumn = sheet.getRange(startRow,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var dates = dateColumn.getDisplayValues().flat();
  var lastRow = dates.lastIndexOf(mDate)+startRow;
    
  //Dashboard is the place for user input where in H5, I5, J5, K5 cell student IDs are entered.  
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  
  //Need to bring all student IDss from those cells of Dashboard to students array. 
  var data = sheet1.getLastColumn();
  var students = [];
  var students = sheet1.getRange(5, 8, 1, data).getValues();  
  
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId);
  for (var i=1; i<=students.length; i++){ // you are looping columwise through cells H5, I5, J5, K5 in row 5.
    if (students[i+7][0] !== ''){
      sheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
      range1 = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, 6);
      
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,1).setValue(dates);
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,2).setValue(students[i+7][0].toString());
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,3).setValue(students[i+7][0].toString() + umailPattern);
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,4).setValue('');
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,5).setValue('');
      range1.getCell(lastRow+1,6).setValue(sheetName);     
    }
  }  
}
```

[image: Input values with Cell info at the Dashboard sheet]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand about your input and output you expect. Especially, I cannot understand about `(G5), (H5), (H5 + K3)`. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of input and output you expect? And also, can I ask you about the detail of current issue of your script?

Comment: Please add the textual error message and simplied version of your code ([mcve]).

Comment: @Tanaike my inputs are in the attached image. for example, I will select from subject ICTE4215 (F5), Date 2020-08-20 (G5), Student ID 01 is 1902011 (H5), Student ID 02 is 1902015 (I5), Student ID 02 is 1902024 (J5), Student ID 04 is 1902036 (K5). based on the input in K6, the function onePeriod() will be called. The output sheet will be like the sheet given after the first 5 lines of the post having column (i) Date, (ii) Student ID, (iii) Umail, (iv) Latitude, (v) Longitude, (vi) subject. The issues is, the code does not insert the inputs in the output sheet, can't find where is the error.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying. I understood `the code does not insert the inputs in the output sheet, can't find where is the error.`. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand about your goal. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your goal from your question. I apologize for this, again.

Comment: @Tanaike please check now. The input values with cell information from the Dashboard sheet are given at the attached image. And the output sheet name will be ICTE4115 (values in cell F5). The output pattern is given just above my codes in the post.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike there are two things you have to consider. 1. It is not the last row of the sheet where you will insert data but it is the last row of the given date (G5 cell value) in the destination sheet. 2. H5, I5, J5 and K5 cell may have one or more blank/empty cells, for example, there is two student IDs - one in H5 and another one is in I5. So two rows will be created in destination sheet one for H5 values and one for I5 values. Please check these conditions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your replying, I cannot understand about it. I apologize for my poor English skill. in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I saw it, I noticed that your new question has already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: @Tanaike hi there, I am facing a difficult issue at my project (sample Google Sheet link is given). Could you please assist at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549880/how-to-insert-the-email-address-by-querying-corresponding-id-using-google-app-sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- When the cell "K6" is edited, your script of `onePeriod()` is run. (Do you use OnEdit event trigger?)
- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "K3, F5, G5, H5, I5, J5, K5" from the source sheet ("Dashboard").
- You want to put the converted values to the destination sheet. In this case, the sheet name is the cell "F5". And the sample output situation can be seen at the top of image in your question.
- You want to put the converted values to the next row of last row of the same date in the column "A" on the destination sheet.

In your script, the values are retrieved each cell using `getValue`, `getDisplayValue()` and `getValues()`. And the values are put using `setValue` in the loop. By this, the process cost will be high. So in this modification, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.

   - In this case, `getDisplayValues()` is used for retrieving the values. And when the values are converted, "Student ID" is converted to the number type.
2. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
3. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.

When above flow is reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function onePeriod() {
  const srcSheetName = "Dashboard";
  
  // 1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [[,,,,,k3],,[f5,g5,...h5i5j5k5]] = srcSheet.getRange("F3:K5").getDisplayValues();
  
  // 2. Convert the values for putting to the destination sheet.
  const dstValues = h5i5j5k5.reduce((ar, e) => {
    if (e != "") ar.push([g5, Number(e), e + k3, , , f5]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // 3. Put the converted values to the destination sheet.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(f5);
  const dstCurrentValues = dstSheet.getRange(`A2:A${dstSheet.getLastRow()}`).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const index = dstCurrentValues.lastIndexOf(dstValues[0][0]) + 2;
  dstSheet.insertRowsAfter(index, dstValues.length);
  dstSheet.getRange(index + 1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are put to the next row of the last row of destination sheet.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your sample input and output values in your question. So when your actual situation is different from this sample, the script might not work. So please be careful this.
- When I could saw your shared Spreadsheet, I noticed the following 2 important points. Please be careful them.

  1. When I saw it, I noticed that the same function names (2 functions `onePeriod()`) are used in `macros.gs` and `manualentry.gs`.
  2. The last lines of the function `onePeriod()` in `manualentry.gs` which uses my script has the scripts which uses `dashboard` which is not declared.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Please check my spreadsheet at this link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PZmmhqGKC9vCaxRRBUj_YFSSvS4RwaS7Y7LWp1pwQs4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can also check the code of the sheet by going to Tools --> Script Editor and then check manualentry.gs file. Please check the Manual entry portion in the right hand side of the Dashboard sheet.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? And by the way, when I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I noticed the following 2 important points. Also I added them in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Still not inserting data into the destination sheet. I created the onEdit trigger and changed the function names. You can try to insert data

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that in that case, the cell "F5" is "All". In your sample Spreadsheet, the sheet name of "All" is not included. So an error occurs. So in your case, please select "ICTE4115" and run the script again.

Comment: I know that All is not included. I did what you said, but it is not working

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in my environment, I can confirm that the script works using your sample Spreadsheet. I apologize for this. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your current issue? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, `onePeriodm()` in `manualentry.gs` has my sample script. In this case, it seems that `onePeriod()` is not used. Why do you use `onePeriod()` instead of `onePeriodm()` with the OnEdit event trigger? I cannot understand about this situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: I got the point. Now it is inserting data after the last row of the sheet ICTE4115. Actually what I want is, last row of any date in the sheet. It may be 2020-08-07, 2020-08-10. Not after the last row of data in a sheet. Please check my ICTE4115 sheet

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Actually what I want is, last row of any date in the sheet. It may be 2020-08-07, 2020-08-10. Not after the last row of data in a sheet`. This is due to my poor English skill I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your actual goal, can you provide the result you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Yes, it is working fine but after inserting data, I have to clear the cells. G5 : K5 will be blank or empty and F5 will be set to All and K6 will be reset to 'Please Select'. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I could understand that my sample script worked in your environment. About your new question, how about putting `srcSheet.getRange("F5").setValue("All"); srcSheet.getRange("K6").setValue("Please Select"); srcSheet.getRange("G5:K5").clearContent();` at the last line of `onePeriodm()`?

Comment: The last point is, if I want to insert the data twice (two times) in the destination sheet what I have to do. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton It seems that that question is not yours. How about this? I apologize for my poor English skill. I'm confusing from your comment. Can you explain about the detail information of your comment?

Comment: For some reason I cannot make any new post here. I do not know why? It is part of a voluntary project. I would be really grateful if you could solve my problem stated at the above post. Please assist if you could.

Comment: @Aktaruzzaman Liton Thank you for replying. I could understand that you are [Liton EDU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13869424/liton-edu). I will check it. When I found the solution of your question, I would like to propose the answer.

Comment: My post was closed for accepting answers, not sure why. I modified it and made a new post to be more specific. Could you please check it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63780216/how-to-take-inputs-from-two-columns-of-a-google-sheet-and-place-it-in-a-google-m